# "Tweaking" the cost function to penalize rarer cases more severely

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, pytorch, loss

I have a very unbalanced data set that I am running a CNN on for regression.  Most of the values are 0, while it is possible for the values to range from 0 to 32.

Is it possible to "tweak" the cost function to penalize rarer cases more severely?

I'm using `torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='none')` as my loss function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use **weighted MSE** by applying different coefficients to each data point.

Here is an implementation given by Francisco Massa at https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-implement-weighted-mean-square-error/2547.

```
def mse_loss(input, target):
    return torch.sum((input - target) ** 2)

def weighted_mse_loss(input, target, weight):
    return torch.sum(weight * (input - target) ** 2)
```